# How can I display CakePHP input validation errors in a different spot the default?

Tags: cakephp, validation

Let's say I have field that looks like this in the view:

```
<li class="bigfield">
  <?php echo $form->input('phone', array(
      'placeholder' => 'Phone',
      'label' => false,
      'between' => '<br />'
  )); ?>
</li>
```

If I have a validation rule on this field and validation fails, I see the following HTML:

```
<li class="bigfield">
  <div class="input text required error">
      <br>
      <input name="data[Appointment][email]" type="text" placeholder="Email" 
             maxlength="45" value="" id="AppointmentEmail" class="form-error">
      <div class="error-message">Please enter a valid email address</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I'm like to do something like move the error message div to an entire different part of the page rather then have it inside with the same <li> as the field itself.  What would be the most straight forward way of doing this?

Comment: See the documentation at https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just updating an old post.

The validations errors are automatically passed on to view (as pointed out by @Angel S. Moreno)

```
$this->validationErrors
```

Answer (score 23):

[In you controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html):

```
$this->set('validationErrorsArray', $this->ModelName->invalidFields());
```

You will have `$validationErrorsArray` in your views.

---

**UPDATE (Sept. 2014):**

**From the view**

From CakePHP 2.3 you can access validation errors array from the [view](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-View.html#$validationErrors):

```
$this->validationErrors;
```

**From the controller**

If you tried to save data in the controller you can access validation errors this way:

```
$this->ModelName->validationErrors;
```

If you want to validate data before saving do it this way:

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->request->data);
if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    $this->ModelName->save();
} else {
    $errors = $this->ModelName->validationErrors;
    // handle errors
}
```

[Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)

Comment: It should be noted that in CakePHP 2.x this value is automatically sent to the view

Comment: Careful: This answer is wrong if you already used save() etc to validate your data since this will re-validate it again. Just use $this->Form->error() in your view.

Comment: I was studied 3x and in charged 3x in a long time. Now I have to handle 2x projects and it looks like new framework. Thank for your answer ^_^

Answer (score 4):

From controller you can use:

```
$this->Modelname->validationErrors['TheFieldYouWantToDisplay'] = 'This is not correct'
```

In your case it would be like this in your controller:

`$this->Appointment->validationErrors['email'] = 'Error message'`

This code is just to make a custom error message on the fly. But you can also define $validate in the model and do it like how brancer has described it.